# Save multiple dates of an event in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm building a system that shows "events for this month", listed by day and hour.

When I create the event, I set a start date, an end date and a hour.

Let's say that one event starts at 07-10-2011 and ends 07-12-2011. The problem is that some days in this date range will not feature the event. As an example, this event may happen all days and at the same hour, except some few days where it will not happen or has a different hour (think about a show with an opening date different than the rest of the days).

I'm using PHP, MySQL and Codeigniter and my doubt is about the right way to save those dates in the database. Another table with all the dates and the event ID, or save them all in a field inside the event row? Or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create two tables.  The first table is an `events` table, and the other is an `events_dates` table.  This way you can create a single event and have as many dates linked to it as you want.

The `events_dates` table can be as detailed or simple as you want.  If it were me, I'd probably have a `start_time` and `end_time` column, as well as an `event_id` and any other data you want.

Comment: Thanks, your solution clearly works but I fear that the events_dates table will get very large. AurelioDeRosa's idea of saving the exceptions instead of the dates seems better to me.

Comment: mysql tables are meant to handle extremely large amounts of data.  Just make sure you index everything properly and all your queries will work just fine.  Having an exceptions table will probably take more work to produce nice, human readable date ranges.

Comment: Your last sentence left me undecided... You think it would be a better solution to populate a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the range date in a table and then create an "exception" table where you can store your exceptions.

Comment: I like this idea. This should solve the "bulky table" issue if I save the exception instead of the "featuring" days (the exception are much less that the days of the event)

Comment: Exactly. In the average case, the exceptions is very few.